# R: Extract a number after a specific word

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a column like below:

```
C1
we-23 pcs,qw-4 pcs
we-30 pcs
er-21 pcs,we-2 pcs
tr-23 pcs
we-0 pcs, re-2 pcs
we-0 pcs
NA
```

I want to extract the quantities of "we" in numeric format, with NAs preserved and no character(0).
I used:

```
C2 <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(str_extract_all(C1, "we-*\\d+"), "\\d+"))
```

Result:

```
C2
23
30
2
0
0
0
NA
```

However, I want to get the tr-23 pcs entry to be different than we-0 pcs. So I am using another logical column to find "we" in C1.
**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Do you mean `str_extract_all(C1, "(?<=we-)\\d+")` and `str_extract_all(C1, "(?<=tr-)\\d+")`?

Comment: Arani, can you please provide some feedback: do you need to extract numbers after `we-` to one column and those after `tr-` into another?

Comment: Nope, I just need the numbers after `we-`. And if possible, then the total in another column. Basically, `we-` marks are special, others have same importance. Even `we-0` has special meaning and need to be separated from where `we-` is not present. I will try your solution and update here.

Comment: Your suggestion is giving me `0` for `we-0` and `character(0)` for missing `we-`. Wrapping it in `as.numeric` did the trick. Thank you so much. Please make an answer with this and also please explain the `regex` syntax a little bit, I am really new to string operations. Also what if I use `str_extract` instead as I will only have maximum one `we-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
C2 <- as.numeric(str_extract(C1, "(?<=we-)\\d+"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CqyWaB/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<=we-)` - a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches a position that is preceded with `we-`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.